# numpy.sum not returning expected value

Tags: python, numpy, sum, primes

I'm working through project euler problems.

'Find the sum of all the primes below two million'

I've built a prime checker that I think is pretty fast - any advise on how to improve would be great too.

But, what I've spent the last 30mins working out is that np.sum isn't returning the correct value. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
def isprime(num, primelist):
    #Give primelist it's first value if none exist
    if len(primelist) == 0:
        primelist.append(num)
        return True
    for primes in primelist:
        #Only need to iterate up to square root of num to test primality
        if primes <= math.sqrt(num):
            #If any number is evenly divisble (remainder = 0) the num is not prime
            if num % primes == 0:
                #print('non-prime')
                return False
                break
        #If we have iterated through all primes <= sqrt of num, num is prime
        else:
            primelist.append(num)
            #print('prime')
            return True
            break

lim = 2000000
n = 3
primelist = [2]

while primelist[-1] <= lim:
    isprime(n, primelist)
    n += 1

if primelist[-1] > lim: primelist = primelist[:-1]
primearray = np.asarray(primelist)
print(np.sum(primearray))

sum = 0
for i in primelist:
    sum = sum + i
print(sum)
```

I suppose it could also be the np.asarray that isn't working rather than np.sum

I've iterated through the original list to test the value numpy is returned.

numpy sum = 1179908154

iterating sum = 142913828922

Over 100 times larger. Where am I going wrong please!!

Comment: Why are you even using `numpy` anyway? Just sum the primes as you generate them. Or just `sum(primelist)`. As an aside, your `break` statements following the `return` statements will never be executed so they are sort of pointless.

Comment: The list was populated with integers which wont work with sum, seemed easy to just asarray and sum with numpy. You're right about the breaks :) they were a bit of a leftover of a previous version of the code, removed them now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are using Windows, where the default size of an integer in numpy is 32 bits.  `np.sum(primelist)` is computing the sum using 32 bit integers, and the sum overflows.  You can verify this by computing (with Python integers) `142913828922 % (2**31)`:

```
In [18]: s = 142913828922

In [19]: s % (2**31)
Out[19]: 1179908154
```

That is the value that you got with `numpy.sum(primelist)`.

You can avoid the problem (or at least defer it until the 64 bit integers overflow) by explicitly converting `primelist` to an array of 64 bit unsigned integers, and then computing its sum:

```
np.array(primelist, dtype=np.uint64).sum()
```

Or just don't use numpy when dealing with very large integers.